# my app keeps crashing the moment I press my clickable text on the profile fragment activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

here is my logcat as the app crashes after i press the TextView

```
06-04 12:58:26.944 5680-5680/com.example.sandwichswitch E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sandwichswitch, PID: 5680
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.sandwichswitch/com.example.sandwichswitch.fragmentprofile}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1794)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:574)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:560)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
    at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity(ContextCompat.java:251)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentHostCallback.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentHostCallback.java:166)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1377)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1365)
    at com.example.sandwichswitch.fragmentprofile.onClick(fragmentprofile.java:44)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

here is the java part of the activity (the fragmentprofile activity)

```
package com.example.sandwichswitch;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class fragmentprofile extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
@Nullable
@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentprofile,container,false);
    return view;


}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    TextView textView=getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvtest);

    textView.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.tvtest:
        Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),fragmentprofile.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    }
}
```

and here is the xml part of fragmentprofile

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="profile"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is the manifest, I added it because the log cat said somthing about declaring my activity here but if you keep scroling you can see what i tryed and what were the resaults

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.sandwichswitch">
    
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".createprofile"></activity>
            <activity android:name=".

Profile" />
        <activity android:name=".LogInScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

the log cat said somthing about declaring the activity there but when I add the line

```
<activity android:name="fragmentprofile"
        tools:ignore="Instantiatable"></activity>
```

it still crashes and this is the logcat

```
06-04 13:14:50.370 6273-6273/com.example.sandwichswitch E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sandwichswitch, PID: 6273
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sandwichswitch/com.example.sandwichswitch.fragmentprofile}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.sandwichswitch.fragmentprofile cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.sandwichswitch.fragmentprofile cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: have you declare activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the next section:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.tvtest:
            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),fragmentprofile.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Specificially in the last paramenter of the next line:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),fragmentprofile.class);
```

The method [startActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) as the name states, is used to start activities, not fragments.
The last parameter in your code is passing **fragmentprofile.class** which is wrong. Instead it should be an activity class that you wish to start.

If you need to open a fragment, then read the [Fragment Manager](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager) documentation, as opening fragments is a completely different paradigm from starting an activity.

Answer (score 0):

you are try a start activity in the same fragment

your fragment name is `fragmentprofile` and you are call intent like this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.tvtest:
        Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),fragmentprofile.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    }
}
```

you are call same fragment then it will crash a apk the solution is

```
Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();  //your destination fragment
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment2);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

try this for call fragment to fragment